# What is entomb service?

Tags: services

On many GNU/Linux systems (Arch, Centos) I see the following entry in `/etc/services` file:

```
entomb            775/tcp
```

What is entomb?

I searched the internet for information about it but there's very little information.

Comment: It was first assigned in [RFC 1060](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1060) in March 1990; but that document doesn’t specify what it’s for (other than a service named “entomb”).